# SVG <use> element referring external SVG ignores internal definitions

Tags: html, svg

I have some SVG code which has internal `defs` - (here it's the gradient underneath the 'A' character)

With the SVG inline - [It looks like this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9wvsLtth/3/).

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 13.8 13.6" enable-background="new 0 0 13.8 13.6" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <path fill="#231F20" d="M5.1,7.1L4.2,9.9l-1.9,0L5.5,0l2.3,0l3.2,9.9l-2,0L8.2,7.1L5.1,7.1z M7.9,5.7L7.1,3.3C7,2.7,6.8,2,6.6,1.4
  l0,0C6.5,2,6.3,2.7,6.1,3.3L5.4,5.7L7.9,5.7z" />
  </g>
  <linearGradient id="textColor" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-7.424569e-007" y1="12.3054" x2="13.8333" y2="12.3054">
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#EC1C24" />
    <stop offset="0.1675" style="stop-color:#F6921E" />
    <stop offset="0.3695" style="stop-color:#FFF100" />
    <stop offset="0.5616" style="stop-color:#8BC53F" />
    <stop offset="0.7882" style="stop-color:#26A9E0" />
    <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#652D90" />
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="0" y="11" fill="url(#textColor)" width="13.8" height="2.7" />
</svg>
```

Now with the `use` element I can externally refer to that same SVG [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9wvsLtth/5/).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="textColor" viewBox="0 0 13.8 13.6" enable-background="new 0 0 13.8 13.6">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-7.424569e-007" y1="12.3054" x2="13.8333" y2="12.3054">
        <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#EC1C24" />
        <stop offset="0.1675" style="stop-color:#F6921E" />
        <stop offset="0.3695" style="stop-color:#FFF100" />
        <stop offset="0.5616" style="stop-color:#8BC53F" />
        <stop offset="0.7882" style="stop-color:#26A9E0" />
        <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#652D90" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path fill="#231F20" d="M5.1,7.1L4.2,9.9l-1.9,0L5.5,0l2.3,0l3.2,9.9l-2,0L8.2,7.1L5.1,7.1z M7.9,5.7L7.1,3.3C7,2.7,6.8,2,6.6,1.4
  l0,0C6.5,2,6.3,2.7,6.1,3.3L5.4,5.7L7.9,5.7z" />
    <rect x="0" y="11" fill="url(#gradient)" width="13.8" height="2.7" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg>
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#textColor"></use>
</svg>
```

So far so good.

The problem is when I take that same SVG, and place it in an external file, and refer to it from the html file - the internal gradient is ignorred!!

To test this:

I have 2 files in the same directory:

1. **symbol.html**

   ```
   <!doctype html>

   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>

   <body>
     <svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="symbol.svg#textColor"></use></svg>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. **symbol.svg**

   ```
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
     <symbol id="textColor" viewBox="0 0 13.8 13.6" enable-background="new 0 0 13.8 13.6">
           <defs>
               <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-7.424569e-007" y1="12.3054" x2="13.8333" y2="12.3054">
                   <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#EC1C24" />
                   <stop offset="0.1675" style="stop-color:#F6921E" />
                   <stop offset="0.3695" style="stop-color:#FFF100" />
                   <stop offset="0.5616" style="stop-color:#8BC53F" />
                   <stop offset="0.7882" style="stop-color:#26A9E0" />
                   <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#652D90" />
               </linearGradient>
           </defs>
           <path fill="#231F20" d="M5.1,7.1L4.2,9.9l-1.9,0L5.5,0l2.3,0l3.2,9.9l-2,0L8.2,7.1L5.1,7.1z M7.9,5.7L7.1,3.3C7,2.7,6.8,2,6.6,1.4
           l0,0C6.5,2,6.3,2.7,6.1,3.3L5.4,5.7L7.9,5.7z" />
           <rect x="0" y="11" fill="url(#gradient)" width="13.8" height="2.7" />
       </symbol> 
   </svg>
   ```

**Result:**

There is no gradient!

So how can I use the external SVG which supports internal definitions?

Comment: For some reason the editor is not displaying the SVG in symbol.svg

Comment: Try moving the gradient outside the symbol definition. I.e. as a sibling of the `<symbol>` element rather than a child of the `<symbol>` element.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks. This seems to work regarding the demo files which I posted. In my project it's not working for some reason.

Comment: Another observation: Firefox is allowing me to access the SVG file, however Chrome is blank and complains with the following msg: Unsafe attempt to load URL symbol.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: Do you use `<base>` tags in your project?

Comment: No I don't use `<base>` tags in the project

Comment: My first guess is that the `url()` references are getting confused by Firefox's clone method of implementing `<use>` elements.  Are you able to run a local server to test on Chrome (the error you're getting is because Chrome treats all local file references as cross-domain requests)?

Comment: Sounds like https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=450470.